# How do I compile a 64-bit native C++ DLL in VS 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit

I'm trying to port a native ATL C++ in-proc COM server to 64 bit in Visual Studio 2008. I've opened the Configuration Manager, added "x64" platform. Now I have 6 configurations - 3 for Win32 that compile and link fine and 3 for x64 that compile fine, but make the linker emit the following error:

```
\Debug64\Objects\common.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

what do I change to make this go away?

UPD: Resolved, the problem source was surprisingly dumb, see my answer below.

Comment: Have your tried to make a clean to make sure that all .obj files are recompiled with the correct target machine?

Comment: Yes, the problem persists even for clean builds.

Answer (score 2):

Did you install the "[x64 compiler and tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246588%28VS.80%29.aspx)" component during the visual studio installation?

Also check these settings: ([copied from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s%28VS.80%29.aspx))

> - /MACHINE (Specify Target Platform) is set to /MACHINE:IA64 or /MACHINE:X64.
> - Register Output is turned OFF. For more information, see Linker Property Pages.
> - Target Environment is set to /env x64 or /env ia64. For more information, see MIDL Property Pages: General.
> - Validate Parameters is cleared and reset to the default value. For more information, see MIDL Property Pages: Advanced.
> - If Debug Information Format was set to /ZI in the Win32 project configuration, then it is set to /Zi in the 64-bit project configuration. For more information, see /Z7, /Zi, /ZI (Debug Information Format).
> - Values of WIN32 are replaced by WIN64 for /D (Preprocessor Definitions).

Comment: Visual C++ does not set all what is needed for x64 compilation. IMO, the most important points are the first (found in Configuration properties/Linker/Advanced) and the last (found in Configuration properties/C/C++/Preprocessor definitions).

Answer (score 0):

Are you *sure* the target machine for common.obj is x86? Because the linker is telling you it is not.
Check in solution->properties->configuration that Platform really is x64, and also set it in project->properties->linker->advanced->target machine. and rebuild.

Comment: What exactly do I check to ensure that the target machine for that .obj file is right?

Comment: did you try both things I mentioned? 
Btw if you want to check manually, open the file in a text or hex editor and look for a line containng '/manifestdependency' or 'processorArchitecture' it will tell what platfrom it was compiled for. Or easier, if you let the linker emit map files, the addresses will all be 64bits long instead of 32.

Comment: Yes, there's a problem: /manifestdependency:"type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC90.CRT' version='9.0.21022.8' processorArchitecture='x86' but how do I fix that?

Comment: Yes, the preprocessor defs and the linker settings are set up right. And I don't use MIDL anywhere in the project.

Comment: in that caes: I'm clueless; unless: do you have per-file settings for compilation? Open your vcproj file in a text editor and check if there's any <fileconfiguration> block for the file that produces common.obj (I'd guess that would be common.cpp)?

Answer (score 0):

A common problem is failing to use a Debug64 and Release64 directory. Exact names don't matter that much, but if you end up mixing 32 and 64 bits .objs, .libs or .dlls in a single directory, the linker will have issues.

A quick way to determine if this contributed is by doing a clean build. If the link problem doesn't disappear, then mixing of intermediate binaries was not the cause

Answer (score 0):

Well, the real reason was surprisingly simple. We don't use a .cmd file shipped with VS for setting the environment variables but instead use our own equivalent .cmd file. That file set the %PATH% variable for 32-bit cl.exe and that's exactly why C++ source was compiled with a 32-bit compiler. The soluton is to iether use the .cmd for x64 compilation shipped with VS or to craft a custom .cmd file setting %PATH% appropriately.